# Can't control brightness on Sony Vaio laptop with Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, brightness

I just did a fresh Windows Vista install on my Sony Vaio VGN-AR71J and all the drivers are there, but the control for the brightness adjustment is gone.

When I tried to run the Vaio Power Management application, Windows shows an error, "SPM module has stopped working".

The computer is working ok, but I am unable to control the brightness.

Answer (score 0):

Sony Vaio drivers has dependency with together, you should read the description of each driver in Sony support web site and install them respectively.